# Triangle inequality in complex numbers. Why do we need a mod sign?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

In the above derivation for the triangle inequality: $|z_1 + z_2| \geq ||z_1| - |z_2||$

Why do we need to put a mod sign over $|z_1| - |z_2|$?
Would it be wrong if we ignore it?
In the derivation process we get $|z_1 + z_2|^2 \geq (|z_1| - |z_2|)^2$ and we can cancel the squares from both sides here without any tension.

Comment: If $|z|<|w|$ then $|z+w|\ge |z|-|w|$ is trivially true, but $|z+w|\ge ||z|-|w||$ is non-trivially true.

Comment: When you see a result of the form $u\ge|v|$, it will also be true that $u\ge v$, but that's not nearly as detailed if $v<0$, so it makes sense to mention $u\ge|v|$ if it's provable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This prevents the trivial case $|z_2|>|z_1|$, indeed  by triangle inequality we obtain

$$|z_1-z_2|+|z_2|\ge |z_1-z_2+z_2|=|z_1| \iff |z_1-z_2|\ge |z_1|-|z_2|$$

but the case with $|z_2|>|z_1|$ is trivially true then

$$|z_1-z_2|\ge ||z_1|-|z_2||$$

is always true.

Answer (score 2):

It's not called a mod sign, but $|z_1-z_2|\ge ||z_1|-|z_2||$ is non-trivially true whereas $|z_1-z_2|\ge|z_1|-|z_2|$ is trivially true. Hence the difference in use.

Comment: What do you mean by trivially true? So, it means we can use any result?

Comment: Which one should we prefer?

Comment: If something is "trivially true," then it is immediately obvious. In this case, it is obvious that $|z_1-z_2|\ge |z_1|-|z_2|$. It depends on the scenario. Sometimes, you'll need to use the trivial one (given directly by the Triangle Inequality) and sometimes you'll need to use the nontrivial one.

Comment: So, in the solutions, which one do you think should we use?

Comment: Like the trivial or non-trivial inequality?

Comment: Use the trivial inequality to prove the nontrivial inequality ofc